# rdlc CountDistinct where status = 1

Tags: vb.net, report, rdlc

I would like to count distinct values from dataset with `where` condition.

This is as far as i did:

```
CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!Status.Value = 1, Count(Fields!Id.Value),nothing))
```

Or

```
IIF(Fields!Status.Value = 1, Count(Fields!Id.Value),nothing)
```

but it doesnt work.

Comment: Just figured out a problem. I had to write CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!Status.Value = true, Fields!Id.Value, nothing)) because my DataSet Status was set as Boolean. :)

Comment: @Briwjan mark write it as answer it helped me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sum(IIF(Fields!Status.Value = 1, 1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18705278/5407188) provided by Alex_Kr will work when there is no duplicate value in the Id field.

By the use of CountDistinct instead of Count, I am assuming there is a need to remove duplicates. The below code would work with Count Distinct,

```cs
CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!Status.Value = 1, Fields!Id.Value,nothing))
```

This code will perform the CountDistinct operation over the list of Id values where the status is 1.